# Android - Help me with NodeList

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I Have a problem here.
i wanna to test my parser result.

i have a kml document from request to Google Maps. here is my KML document

```
<LineString>
    <coordinates>
        106.826200,-6.297500,0.000000 
        106.826220,-6.297260,0.000000 
        106.826380,-6.297050,0.000000 
        106.826900,-6.296710,0.000000 
        106.827120,-6.296640,0.000000 
        106.827120,-6.296640,0.000000 
        106.827170,-6.296510,0.000000 
        106.827140,-6.296370,0.000000 
        106.827140,-6.296370,0.000000 
        106.826210,-6.295840,0.000000 
        106.824970,-6.295220,0.000000 
        106.823550,-6.294580,0.000000 
        106.822690,-6.293830,0.000000 
        106.822860,-6.293800,0.000000 
        106.823820,-6.294160,0.000000 
        106.825240,-6.294830,0.000000 
        106.830400,-6.297550,0.000000 
        106.831360,-6.298100,0.000000 
        106.885600,-6.293860,0.000000 
    </coordinates>
</LineString>
```

and this is my code:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
        for(int s = 0; s < nl.getLength(); s++){
            Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
            NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for(int x = 0; x < configItems.getLength(); x++){
                Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
                NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
                pathConent = path.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
```

the parser is succesfully, and i can draw route on google map. but now i wanna know how its works, so i want to print the coordinates to TextView. and here is my new code:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
        for(int s = 0; s < nl.getLength(); s++){
            Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
            NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for(int x = 0; x < configItems.getLength(); x++){
                Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
                NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
                pathConent = path.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
    String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < tempContent.length; i++){
                koor.setText("Latitude, Longitude:\n" + tempContent[i] + "\n");
            }
```

but why in my TextView i only got a first coordinats (106.826200,-6.297500,0.000000). can u help me to solve my problems?

thanks and im really sorry about my english >_<

Comment: try NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("coordinates"); instead of NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString"); Also you can put a breakpoint in there and see if variables are getting the values you expect them to.

Comment: From what i can see you should just get the last coords since you write a new value to the `TextView` on each iteration of the for loop.  You should use `StringBuilder` to build the text you want to display and then use a single `TextView.setText` instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
    String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
    koor.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < tempContent.length; i++){
        koor.append("Latitude, Longitude:\n" + tempContent[i] + "\n");
    }
```

instead of

```
String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tempContent.length; i++){
            koor.setText("Latitude, Longitude:\n" + tempContent[i] + "\n");
        }
```